# Looking for a way to pass an object array from one embedded script to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameter-passing

The object array is built here in the first script..."order_items".  I want to pass it into the second script so I can loop through values and build a pixel to render to my screen.  I'm stuck trying to pass the array.

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < OrderItemsReceived.Count; i++)
{
    <script type="text/javascript" id="pepper" data-search="order_items"> 
        var order_items = [{
            'name':ProductName',
            'sku': SKU',
            'price': UnitPrice.ToString().Replace(",", "")',
            'quantity': Quantity.ToString()'
        }]
    </script>
}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var script_tag = document.getElementById('pepper');
        var order_items = script_tag.getAttribute("data-search");

        var order_id = @Model.OrderId;
        var pixel_html = '';
        var integration = 'DYNAMIC';
        var program_id = 7302;


        if (order_id && order_items) {
            jQuery.each( order_items, function (i, order_item) {
                pixel_html += '&' + 'ITEM_ID' + i + '=' + order_item.sku +
                              '&' + 'ITEM_PRICE' + i + '=' + order_item.price +
                              '&' + 'QUANTITY' + i + '=' + order_item.quantity;
            });

            if (pixel_html) {
           pixel_html = '<iframe src="https://t.pikespeak.com/track?' +
                'INT=' + integration +
                '&' + 'PROGRAM_ID' + '=' + program_id +
                '&' + 'ORDER_ID' + '=' + order_id +
                pixel_html +
                '" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
            }
        }
        $('body').append(pixel_html);
    </script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just fine to access it all from over when it is simply a global entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I solved the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="pepper" data-search="order_items">
    alert("hello");
    var order_items = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.OrderItemsReceived.OrderItemsReceived));
    var order = [];
    var order_listItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < order_items.length; i++){
        var orderList = order_items[i];
        order = [{
            'sku': orderList.SKU,
            'price': orderList.UnitPrice,
            'quantity': orderList.Quantity
        }]
        order_listItems.push(order);
    }
```

I chose to go ahead with a  json object because my array would be constructed of key, value pairs.  Once I realized this, the scope of the variable was no longer the issue.